# Navbar menu responsive on ipad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

I have a problem with the header on my website in tablet and ipad (mini and air). 
The menu dosen't became responsive, it work only on pc and smartphone

I tried it on Bootply and it worked:

http://www.bootply.com/lM8zFcgKl7

The screen on my site:
[image: Screen of my site]

My website url: http://www.hexaweb.it/clienti/noi

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Mobile_Detect.php` which is a really cool tool to check for devices.

I've also written two different stylesheets `screen.css` and `mobile.css`

So basically it goes like this:

```
<? if($detect->isMobile()) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo $siteroot ?>css/mobile.css" type="text/css">
<? } else { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo $siteroot ?>css/screen.css" type="text/css">
<? } ?>
```

It also supports Tablets `if($detect->isTablet())`

Answer (score 0):

Its the `nav` `width` issue that you are facing Reduce the `font-size` and `padding` of li for tablet screen and then it will get aligned.

Comment: I want  make the navbar header responsive on tablet (ipad) like smartphone, with the toggle button, but it don't appear

Comment: Bootstrap make the nav responsive as in mobile till width of screen 992 px. So your website is fine till 992 px.